# Не собирается android проект при помощи gradle скрипта

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, gradle

Собираю android проект gradle скриптом, вылетают ошибки:

```
H:\workspaces\android-32_1\Test\jni\Detector.cpp:174:22: error: 'ANDROID
_LOG_INFO' was not declared in this scope
H:\workspaces\android-32_1\Test\jni\Detector.cpp:174:97: error: '__andro
id_log_print' was not declared in this scope
```

т. е. не видна библиотека log, в gradle скрипте прописано подключение:

```
ndk {
    moduleName 'Computations'
    cFlags '-DCUSTOM_DEFINE'
    ldLibs 'log'
   stl 'stlport_static'
}
```

Через eclipse вручную проект собирается. Что необходимо поправить в скрипте, чтобы заработало?

Comment: Проблема уже неактуальна. Как починил - не помню)